# WebRTC Android - createPeerConnection() always returns null

Tags: android, webrtc

I'm new to Android and WebRTC, and I have been struggling to get a p2p video connection working between a website and my android device. I have already gotten this working between two websites, so I'm fairly sure my issue lies in the Android side.

When I try to create a new PeerConnection object using PeerConnectionFactory.createPeerConnection(), the result is always null. I am using release vesion M58 of WebRTC.

```
PeerConnection.IceServer iceServer = new PeerConnection.IceServer("http://stun.stun.l.google.com:19302/");
List<PeerConnection.IceServer> servers = new ArrayList<PeerConnection.IceServer>();
servers.add(iceServer);

// Media Constraints
final MediaConstraints mediaConstraints = new MediaConstraints();
mediaConstraints.mandatory.add(new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("OfferToReceiveAudio", "true"));
mediaConstraints.mandatory.add(new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("OfferToReceiveVideo", "true"));
mediaConstraints.optional.add(new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement", "true"));

// Set up remote rendering stuff
rootEGLBase = EglBase.create();
svr = (SurfaceViewRenderer) findViewById(R.id.remote_video);
svr.init(rootEGLBase.getEglBaseContext(), null);
svr.setScalingType(RendererCommon.ScalingType.SCALE_ASPECT_FIT);
svr.setZOrderMediaOverlay(true);
svr.setEnableHardwareScaler(true);

remoteProxyRenderer.setTarget(svr);
remoteRender = remoteProxyRenderer;

// Create a peer connection factory
PeerConnectionFactory.initializeAndroidGlobals(this.ctx, true);
PeerConnectionFactory.Options options = new PeerConnectionFactory.Options();
options.networkIgnoreMask = 0;

PeerConnectionFactory peerConnectionFactory = new PeerConnectionFactory(options);

// wait until my websocket has connected
System.out.println("waiting for websocket to be inited...");
while (this.ws == null);
System.out.println("done wait");
final WebSocket in_scope_ws = this.ws;

// create peer connection observer
PeerConnection.Observer pcObserver = new PeerConnection.Observer() {/* not included - mostly just prints */};

// Create peerconnection
final PeerConnection peerConnection = peerConnectionFactory.createPeerConnection(servers, mediaConstraints, pcObserver);
```

Here is the PeerConnection.Observer anonymous implementation that I removed from the above code. I'm sure that I'm doing a lot of other stuff wrong in here, but I figured I'd wait to solve this until I got the offer/answer exchange working first.

```
PeerConnection.Observer pcObserver = new PeerConnection.Observer() {
    final String TAG = "PEER_CONNECTION_FACTORY";

    @Override
    public void onSignalingChange(PeerConnection.SignalingState signalingState) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onSignalingChange");
    }

    @Override
    public void onIceConnectionChange(PeerConnection.IceConnectionState iceConnectionState) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onIceConnectionChange");
    }

    @Override
    public void onIceConnectionReceivingChange(boolean b) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onIceConnectionReceivingChange");
    }

    @Override
    public void onIceGatheringChange(PeerConnection.IceGatheringState iceGatheringState) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onIceGatheringChange");
    }

    // not sure what to put here
    @Override
    public void onIceCandidate(IceCandidate iceCandidate) {
        System.out.println("AN ICE CANDIDATE HAS BEEN DISCOVERED");
        if (iceCandidate != null && in_scope_ws != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject payload = new JSONObject();
                payload.put("sdpMLineIndex", iceCandidate.sdpMLineIndex);
                payload.put("sdpMid", iceCandidate.sdpMid);
                payload.put("candidate", iceCandidate.sdp);
                JSONObject candidateObject = new JSONObject();
                candidateObject.put("ice", iceCandidate.toString());
                in_scope_ws.sendText(candidateObject.toString());
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //send ice candidate to server - probably need to convert to string and put in JSON object
//                    in_scope_ws.send("")
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onIceCandidatesRemoved(IceCandidate[] iceCandidates) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onIceCandidatesRemoved");
    }

    // pretty sure this is the only garbage I need right now
    @Override
    public void onAddStream(MediaStream mediaStream) {
        System.out.println("IN ADD STREAM");
        if(mediaStream.videoTracks.size()==0) {
            Log.d("onAddStream", "NO REMOTE STREAM");
            System.out.println("NO REMOTE STREAM (PRINTLN)");
        }
        mediaStream.videoTracks.get(0).addRenderer(new VideoRenderer (remoteRender));
//                VideoRendererGui.update(remoteRender, 0, 0, 100, 100, RendererCommon.ScalingType.SCALE_ASPECT_FILL, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRemoveStream(MediaStream mediaStream) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onRemoveStream");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDataChannel(DataChannel dataChannel) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onDataChannel");
    }

    @Override
    public void onRenegotiationNeeded() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onRenegotiationNeeded");
    }

    @Override
    public void onAddTrack(RtpReceiver rtpReceiver, MediaStream[] mediaStreams) { Log.d(TAG, "onAddTrack"); }

};
```

Answer (score 2):

Another problem that `createPeerConnection()` returning null could be with wrong configuration of `IceServer`, make sure you set correct `IceServer` and correct credentials.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable verbose logging to trace the problem.

```
org.webrtc.Logging.enableLogToDebugOutput(Logging.Severity.LS_VERBOSE);
```

Also make sure you have granted required runtime permissions (CAMERA, RECORD_AUTDIO)

Answer (score 0):

you need to createLocalMediaStream and set videoHeight videoWidth,createVideoSource,createAudioSource 
before you createPeerConnection.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try that. I only need one way video though, so do I just create my local media stream and ignore it? Or do I just send it and trust the other end not to do anything with it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The peerConnection object was always returned as null.

In my case, the username for one of the turn servers was not set. After setting that, peerConnection object was created successfully.

```
val servers = listOf(
...,    
PeerConnection.IceServer.builder("server_url")
                .setUsername("user_name")
                .setPassword("password")
                .createIceServer()
...

        ) as MutableList<PeerConnection.IceServer>
```